# Is there a different way of writing [class^="top"]?

Tags: html, css, attributes

I am using a program that checks all CSS files and converts all text within brackets `[]` to a color code.

For example I can use: `background-color: [mainBackground];` and in another file I can define `mainBackground` as a color code, so the output could be `background-color: #101010;`

Now I wanted to use the CSS attribute selector:

```
div[class^="top"]{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

But the program I use will tell me that there is no color defined called `class^="top"`.

I cannot bypass or eliminate this conversion, so my question is if there is another way of writing `div[class^="top"]` without brackets?

Comment: Honestly I'd suggest changing the program you're using. Square brackets have been part of CSS for a very long time.

Comment: Have you looked at using a pre-processor language such as SASS or LESS? Perhaps these could suit your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Consider changing the program you are using to replace the colour codes to SASS. It supports [variable substitution](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_) and is designed to work with CSS syntax.

Comment: Why SASS specifically and not other CSS pre-compilers with variable support? Your answer seems to imply that SASS is the only option.

Comment: I would say pre-compilers are all almost the same, but SASS is the most commonly known/used no?

Comment: SASS is an option that I know works for this. Other packages are available but I don't know their featuresets so well.